# Using prependTo to display full size images of thumbnails

Tags: jquery

I have a default image on my site using `prependTo`:

```
$('<li></li>').prependTo('#files')
              .html('<img src="/media/sample1.jpeg" alt="" /><br />')
              .addClass('success');
```

Above the default image are 3 thumbnails, which are written as:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul> 
        <li>
            <a href="/media/glasses1.png" title="styling yourself w/ this armani pair">
                <img src="/media/glasses1.png" width="72" height="72" alt="" /> 
            </a>
        </li> 
        <li>
            <a href="/media/glasses0.png" title="styling yourself w/ this guess pair">
                <img src="/media/glasses0.png" width="72" height="72" alt="" /> 
            </a>
        </li> 
        <li>
            <a href="/media/glasses2.png" title="styling yourself w/ this guess pair">
                <img src="/media/glasses2.png" width="72" height="72" alt="" /> 
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I detect a mouseover on the thumbnail so that I can replace the default image with the full size image of the thumbnail?

Comment: hey @Dat Nguyen, I staggered the chain calls to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone the actual image from the gallery container, just copying the image source does not force the browser to rerender.

**EDIT: From what you describe in your comments I think this should work for you**

```
$('#gallery img').mouseenter(function() {
  var img = $('<img alt=""/>').attr('src', $(this).data('other'));
  $('#files img').replaceWith(img);
});
```

And add a data-other attribute on your thumbnails:

```
<a href="/media/glasses1.png" title="styling yourself w/ this armani pair">
  <img src="/media/glasses1.png" data-other="replacementImage.png" width="72" height="72" alt="" /> 
</a>
```

If you have a naming convention or some other way to determine the url to the new image without adding the attribute, you can do that instead.

Comment: I actually have 2 default images, sample1.jpg and sample2.jpg. When a user hovers over thumbnail 1, I actually want to replace sample1.jpg with another image (1_processed.jpg). How do I distinguish between sample1.jpg and sample2.jpg?

Comment: Then you need to have an ID on the images, and select it with _$('#files img#imageId')_ instead. The same with the gallery images. However, I'm not entirely sure what you mean so could you explain further, perhaps edit it into the question?

Comment: I have 3 thumbnails t1,t2,t3 and 2 default images d1,d2. If user hovers over t1, I want d1 to be replaced by a new image t1_d1. If user hovers over t2, I want d1 to be replaced by a new image t2_d1. d2 never changes. Does that make sense? The code you gave me just shows full size version of a thumbnail, which is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
$('#gallery img').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#files img.success').attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

you'll need to figure out what to do on .mouseleave()

Comment: I actually have 2 default images, sample1.jpg and sample2.jpg. When a user hovers over thumbnail 1, I actually want to replace sample1.jpg with another image (1_processed.jpg). How do I distinguish between sample1.jpg and sample2.jpg?

Comment: I also need to distiguish between thumbnail 1 and thumbnail 2. If mouse hovers over thumbnail 1, I want to replace sample1.jpg with 1_processed.jpg. If mouse hovers over thumbnail 2, I want to replace sample1.jpg with 2_processed.jpg.

Comment: In the example you first posted you only had one, which I deduced was classed "success".  if you have another one you should consider giving them ids and then addressing them by id.  the question then is which of the two you want to update as the users moves over the gallery images